# How to directly move to a view which is added as subview in in third tab iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

First of all sorry for the title.Actually i dont know how to give a appropriate title for this scenario.

I have a login view.Once the authentication is success next view is a tab bar view with four tabs.I created this as follows:

```
UIViewController *firstTab = [[SAHomeView_iPad alloc]initWithNibName:@"SAHomeview_iPad" bundle:nil];
         firstTab.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Home.png"];
         UIViewController *secondTab = [[SAMenuView_iPad alloc]initWithNibName:@"SAMenuView_iPad" bundle:nil];
         secondTab.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu.png"];
         UIViewController *thirdTab = [[SAGraphView_iPad alloc]initWithNibName:@"SAGraphView_iPad" bundle:nil];
         thirdTab.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Graph.png"];
         UIViewController *fourthTab = [[SAAboutView_iPad alloc]initWithNibName:@"SAAboutView_iPad" bundle:nil];
         fourthTab.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"];
         UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
         tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstTab, secondTab,thirdTab,fourthTab, nil];
         SAAppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
         delegate.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

Now in the third tab,i have added a calendar button,which when pressed will give a calendar view.i added this calendar view as subview in third tab.

Now once the user is logged in,there will be a calendar button in the home tab.
Once user tap the calendar button he should move to the calendar view.
This calendar view is actually added as a subview in the third tab.

Can anyone please help me to solve this scenario.
Many thanks in advance.[image: Login]

[image: View after the Login Success]
[image: Calendar view(which is added as subview in third Tab)]

Comment: Now the problem is i want a calendar button in First tab,and when user tap this button he/she to directly move to the calendar view(ie the calendar view which is added as a subview in third tab.). **I cant not understand your problem clearly, please explain in deep**

Comment: Did you mean skip to third tab or present calendar view as modal view? if you need to skip third tab, just try: [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];

Comment: @jessex can i directly load that calendar view as shown in the third image withour presenting.

Comment: @suji No, the view can only have one superview. You need to use two views but share the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friends finally i did it in this way.Thanks for all your help.Hope this help you also.:)

```
- (IBAction)moveToCalendar:(id)sender {
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
    [(SAGraphView_iPad *)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController calendar:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take the calendar view out of your thirdTab view hierarchy and assign it to  it's own custom viewController, so that it can be presented with equal status from any other viewController in your app.

You can then invoke the calendar using a modal storyboard segue or in code using:

```
[self presentViewController:calendarViewController animation:YES completion:NIL];
```

and dismiss it:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

When you present it, you will lose your tab controller context, as the expectation is that you will return to the view that presented it. When you dismiss it, you get that presenting view back with the tab bar context.

Comment: is there any way to load the view without presenting that view,